# libvirt: ERROR Host does not support any virtualization

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, virtualbox, libvirt

That's when I run the command 'virt-install'

```
virt-install --connect=qemu:///system --name=mymachine --ram=4096 --vcpus=2 --check-cpu --os-type=ubuntu --vnc --accelerate --disk=/home/myuser/mymachine/mymachine.qcow2,sparse=true --network=bridge:br0
```

Things I've already checked out:

- kvm modprobe is running (checked with lsmod | grep kvm )
- Virtualization is enabled on my bios
- The flag --hvm

More info:

- Hardware: HP laptop with Intel CPU I5
- OS: Manjaro 20.04 (arch)
- Package: libvirt from community

Virtualbox runs fine so I'm a bit puzzled here. Also, on my other computer the command runs correctly. Any idea about what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
sudo pacman -S qemu ebtables iptables dnsmasq
sudo sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
```